# JsGrid - Auto Increment ID

Tags: javascript, jsgrid

I recently started using JsGrid and I really like it. It is simple to interact with and well documented.

I though face a small issue:

Whenever I insert a new row in the JsGrid application I get asked an ID. If this ID happens to be the same as an already existing ID, it will give my an error on my MySql database (unique key).

Is there a way to fill in the ID for the user and make sure he can not alter it while inserting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Usually ID is generated on the DB level. So user should not provide the ID for new items. Remove ID field from the grid or just make it readonly, removing the `type` attribute.

It's implemented in the sample project, showing how to use jsGrid with PHP + MySQL RESTful backend https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid-php.